# Cast `decimal.NullDecimal` type to int

Tags: go, casting

I am using a variable whose type is `decimal.NullDecimal` (from `github.com/shopspring/decimal`) and want to cast its integer value to be able to compare it with an integer. How should I cast its decimal value?
Here is what I have in code:

```golang
    import (
    // other packages
    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
    )

    type BooksStores struct {
        PublisherShare decimal.NullDecimal `json:"publisher_share"`
    }
    var booksStores BooksStores

    err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&booksStores, binding.JSON)

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    publisherShare := booksStores.PublisherShare


    // Here I want to compare the `publisherShare` value with 0 and 100
    if publisherShare < 0 || publisherShare > 100 {
    // DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Here is what I have tried but none of them didn't success:

```golang
import "https://github.com/spf13/cast"


cast.ToInte(publisherShare) 
cast.ToInte(&publisherShare)
cast.ToInt(publisherShare.Decimal)
cast.ToInt(publisherShare.Decimal)
// but it is casted to zero, I have to use `decimal.NullDecimal` type
// due to the database considerations (later I have to update something)
```

I think I should use the `Cmp` method on the `github.com/shopspring/decimal` package to compare `publisherShare` value with numbers.

Comment: A note on terminology: Go doesn't do typecasting (despite the misnamed package you're using). What you're after is type conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem is solved now, I should have used `var booksStores *BooksStores` instead of `var booksStores BooksStores`.

```golang
    type BooksStores struct {
        PublisherShare decimal.NullDecimal `json:"publisher_share"`
    }
    var booksStores *BooksStores // Here is the place I had to change

    err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&booksStores, binding.JSON)

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    publisherShare := booksStores.PublisherShare

    if publisherShare.Decimal.LessThan(decimal.NewFromInt(0)) || publisherShare.Decimal.GreaterThan(decimal.NewFromInt(100)) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since not all arbitrary-precision decimals can be represented as Go integers, I'd say you should probably convert your int to a decimal with `decimal.NewFromInt(...)`, and then compare using something like [decimal.GreaterThan](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shopspring/decimal#Decimal.GreaterThan):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

func main() {
    // Let's say dec is the decimal we want to compare
    dec := decimal.NewFromInt(42)

    // We compare it to 100
    h := decimal.NewFromInt(100)

    if dec.GreaterThan(h) {
        fmt.Println("> 100")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("<= 100")
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/H40wnVurziX)

---

Note that `decimal.NullDecimal` just holds a `Decimal` and a validity flag, so once you know it's valid you just get the `Decimal` field from it and then compare as shown above.

Comment: You skipped the main problem by using an integer (42) for the`NewFromInt` method. The problem is I can not get the decimal part of the `publisherShare` and `decimal.NewFromInt()` needs an int for arguement. When I use `dec := decimal.NewFromInt(publisherShare.Decimal)` I get an error due to using decimal type instead of int.

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia: you already have a decimal in `PublisherShare`. In your case `dec := publisherShare.Decimal`, no?

Comment: The problem is solved now. I had to use `var booksStores *BooksStores` instead of `var booksStores BooksStores` to get the actual decimal value instead of its zero-value.